# Enlazar dos tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Soy nueva con esto de las BD. Espero me puedan ayudar.

La consulta es entre estas 2 tablas:

--line--

```
  id_line |  region | etapa | line | rel_coord | rel_res
  _______   _______   _____   ____   _________   _____

  1       | region1 |   be  | nom  |   brad    | gary   

  2       | region2 |   be  | ali  |   care    | fabian

  3       | region1 |   fe  | dkt  |   ali     | antho
```

--tr--

```
    id_tr |  enero | febrero  | marzo|
   ______   _____   ________   _____
```

Quiero que me quede así:

```
    region | etapa | line | enero | febrero | marzo |
   _______   _____   ____   _____   _______   _____

   region1 |   be  | nom  |        |        |       |

   region2 |   be  | ali  |        |        |       |

   region1 |   fe  | dkt  |        |        |       |
```

Lo intente de varias formas. Una de ellas de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT l.region, l.etapa, l.linea, t.enero, t.febrero, t.marzo from line l, tr t;
```

Dando como resultado todas:(sin mostear los registros ya tenia región, etapa y linea)

```
  region | etapa | line | enero | febrero | marzo |
  _______   _____   ____   _____   _______   _____
```

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio @mexflow. Por favor comparte la estructura de tu tabla. Si no sabes cómo ver la estructura de una tabla, ejecuta `DESC tabla` y te mostrará sus columnas y tipos de datos de las columnas.

Answer (score 13):

Tal y como a comentado nuestro compañero [Alonso Carrasco](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13558/4684) para unir dos o más tablas se necesita crear llaves foráneas, pero si dices que eres nueva, tal vez con su comentario no basta y necesitas una explicación.

**COMO UNIR DOS TABLAS**

Primero, para relacionar tablas, tienes que tener claras cuantos tipos de relaciones existen:

- Relación uno a uno (1:1): esta relación se da, por ejemplo, entre dos tablas llamadas `Usuario` y `DNI`. Un `DNI`solo puede pertenecer a un `Usuario` y un `Usuario` solo puede tener un `DNI`. Así que, por lo general, se crearía una llave foránea de `Usuario` a `DNI`, dando como resultado un nuevo campo en la tabla `DNI` que referenciaría al id del usuario o al contrario, ya que en este caso daria igual donde poner la llave foránera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Relación uno a muchos (1:n): en esta relación sucede lo mismo que en 1:1, ya que por ejemplo, entre dos tablas llamadas `Usuario` y `Vehiculo`, pasaría que un `Vehiculo` puede tener como dueño a un `Usuario`, pero un `Usuario` puede tener más de un `Vehiculo`, se relaciona de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Relación muchos a muchos (n:m): esta relación es un poco más laboriosa, pero es igual de simple de entender. Tenemos dos tablas llamas `Asignatura` y `Alumno`, así que pensamos y decimos la formula mágica, un `Alumno` puede tener muchas `Asignaturas` y una `Asignatura` puede tener muchos `Alumnos`, por lo que este seria un caso de relación muchos a muchos. Cuando te topes con esta relación, acuérdate que **siempre** se tiene que crear una tabla auxiliar entre las dos, que recoga los id de cada tabla, justo como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La funcion de esta tabla auxiliar es que recogera los id de cada tabla y los enlazara, por ejemplo, un registro de esta tabla es:

Alumno 1 y Asignatura 1.
Alumno 2 y Asignatura 1.
Alumno 1 y Asignatura 3.

Y las dos seria claves primarias.

**RELACIONAR TABLAS POR SENTENCIA**

Una vez que tengas esto claro, solo te faltaría saber como se pueden unir esta tablas cuando quieres construir una sentencia. Para unir tablas puedes utilizar los INNER JOIN, de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT u.nombre, u.direccion, d.numero
FROM Usuario u
INNER JOIN DNI d
ON u.id = d.Usuario_id
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Despúes de agragar el `FROM 'tabla1' 'acronimo1'`, añades `INNER JOIN 'tabla a relacionar' 'acronimo' ON acronimo1.'campo enlazado' = acronimo2.'campo enlazado'. Siempre se tienen que enlazar los campos que sean el "mismo", es decir el`id`de`Usuario`, siempre sera igual al campo`Usuario_id`de`DNI`.

En caso de que necesites relaciona mas de una tabla, simplemente sigue añadiendo `INNER JON ... ON ... = ...`, por ejemplo, suponiendo que la tabla `Usuario` tenga un campo `Vehiculo_id` con relación al `id` de la tabla `Vehiculo`:

```
SELECT u.nombre, u.direccion, d.titulo, v.marca
FROM Usuario u
INNER JOIN DNI d
ON u.id = d.Usuario_id
INNER JOIN Vehiculo v
ON u.Vehiculo_id = v.id
WHERE u.id = 1
```

También se puede utilizar diferentes `JOIN`, además del [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) también esta el [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), [RIGHT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp), [FULL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp), etc..

**UNIR DOS SENTENCIAS**

De todas formas, en caso de que quieras unir dos sentencias que no tengan ninguna relación, te recomiendo utilizar [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) que te permite justo esto. Por ejemplo, en tu caso, puede ser:

```
SELECT region, etapa, linea FROM line
UNION
SELECT enero, febrero, marzo FROM tr;
```

Espero haber solucionado y aclarado aún mas tus dudas. Si necesitas cualquier cosa o no entiendes algo de lo que te explico, por favor no dudes en comentármelo. Además, animo a todo aquel que quiera añadir algún otro caso y así poder tener una entrada más completa.

¡Suerte con tu BD!

Comment: Lo intente con UNON anteriormente,ya que solo me interesaba unirlas sin ninguna relacion. pero me muestra un Error Code:1271. Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION' .....Y esta como me explicaste en tu ejemplo

Comment: Eso es porque tienes las dos tablas con diferente codificación o codificación **no unicode**. Prueba utilizando `COLLATE latin1_general_cs ` al final de la sentencia. Si no funciona revisa tu código en busca de acentos o `ñ`. En [este](http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/84/Que-es-el-Collation-en-SQL-.aspx) enlace te define la sentencia `COLLATE`, por si no te soluciono el problema y quieres seguir buscando. ¡Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr la unión de la tabla llamada "line" y "tr" con las columnas que deseas, basta hacer un INNER JOIN, como el siguiente:

```
SELECT line.region, line.etapa, line.line, tr.enero, tr.febrero, tr.marzo
FROM line
INNER JOIN tr
ON line.id_line = tr.id_tr;
```

Con ese código, lograrás lo que pides, saludos.

Answer (score -2):

Mirá generalmente yo cuando voya unir dos tablas les integro llaves foreneas, de esta forma jamas he tenido problemas para consultar las tablas y unirlas, vamos a pensar que en la tabla; **TR** le agregas como llave forea el id de la tabla **LINE** y en el Select ya los unes algo como esto;

`SELECT l.region, l.etapa, l.linea, t.enero, t.febrero, t.marzo FROM line l CROSS JOIN tr t`

Comment: No me funciono, incluso le intente agregando      ** `SELECT l.region, l.etapa, l.linea, t.enero, t.febrero, t.marzo FROM line l CROSS JOIN tr t ON tr.rel_line= line.id_line ;` **     No me mostro error pero sigo con el mismo problema :(

Comment: Pero si agregaste el indice en la tabla TR para crear la relación.

Comment: Asi es, se llama 'rel_line'

Comment: A la tabla TR en el campo nuevo que has creado que se llama rel_line le agregaste el mismo id (de la tabla line, ose al id de la tabla line), es decir si has relacionado tu tabla TR a la tabla line?. en caso contrario, seria de mucha utilidad ver como tiene tus tablas para construir la sentencia sql.