# join 2 tablas a través de 3 columnas SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito la consulta de:

- Name: El nombre de pais(country.Name),Population(country.population), Capital(**City**.IDLa ciudad capital del país), Number of cities(Count(**City**.ID))

El número de ciudades del país, para esto he hecho un INNER JOIN a country con City para mostrar sus capitales con el `country.capital` y `city.ID`, que resuelve sin problema, pero necesito tomar el `Country.code` con el `City.ID` para hacer un `COUNT(city.ID)` y muestro el numero de ciudades.

En general la pregunta es ¿Cómo junto 2 tablas con diferentes ID?, es decir `city.id -> country.capital` (esto para capital de pais) y `city.ID -> country.COde` (para `COUNT ciudades)`.

> **PD:** esto es para desarrollo de PHP.

```
SELECT cty.Name, cty.Population, c.Name ,COUNT(c.Name) as `total_cities` ,cty.HeadOfState, cty.Continent 
FROM `City` c INNER JOIN `Country` cty 
ON c.ID = cty.Capital group by cty.Name,cty.Code
```

Lo anterior muestra imagen (arriba)

```
SELECT co.code AS 'cod pais', Count(ci.ID) AS 'ciudades' 
FROM country AS co INNER JOIN city AS ci 
ON co.Code=ci.CountryCode
GROUP BY co.name;
```

Lo anterior muestra imagen abajo

[image: captura sql]

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar las columnas de la tabla country y city? Podrías enlazar ambas tablas con una clave ajena, tal vez te sirva este post https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13556/enlazar-dos-tablas-en-mysql

Comment: CITY= ID, Name, CountryCode, District, Population
Country = Code, Name, Continent, HeadOfState, Capital, region  y algunos otras columnas mas q no necesito. claro esa es la pregunta. utilizo clave foranea de countrycode para contar ciudades, pero no me sirve para mostrar su country.capital. para esto me toca usar join city.id = country.Capital

Comment: Y en la tabla country tienes la columna CountryCode?

Comment: si ..perdona mientras respondias estaba editando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta lo que hemos hablado, podíamos tener la consulta, puedes hacer un GROUP BY con los campos que necesitas y contar las filas que produce la tabla City. Añado una subconsulta en el select.

```
SELECT 
  co.Code, 
  co.Name, 
  co.Capital, 
  count(*) AS ciudades,
  (select ci_1.name FROM City ci_1 WHERE ci_1.code = co.code) AS capitalPais
FROM Country.co JOIN City ci ON co.Code = ci.CountryCode
GROUP BY co.Code, co.Name, co.Capital
```

Comment: hasta ahi..muestra bien el conteo de ciudades..pero necesito el NOMBRE de la ciudad capital de cada pais..por ende, necesita el Country.Capital = city.ID

Comment: ¿El nombre de la capital de cada país no es la columna co.Capital?

Comment: country.capital es un codigo de ciudad, no el nombre. entonces para sacar el nombre hay q unir country.code y city.code.. pero esta union no me sirve para sacar COUNT cities

Comment: no entiendo el sentido del join en esa consulta... y otra cosa, esto solamente funciona en versiones viejas de mysql. en una version nueva, a ese group by le falta una columna...

Comment: La columna que le falta al group by, te refieres a la subconsulta?